# How to deploy yeoman angularjs project to IIS?

Tags: angularjs, iis-7, yeoman-generator-angular

I'm trying to deploy my angular application to IIS in windows server. I'm currently using grunt to build the app and then have a web.config to point to my index.html in the dist folder.

The problem is that is not finding any vendor.css or main.css, nor any vendor.js or scripts.js files. I'm not sure if there are tags I can include to my web.config so that it knows where to look for these files. Also, I copied all folders within the dist and pasted the into the root directory of the application and it seemed to work, but then it could not find components I'm currently using in the app.

This how my website looks with current setup:
[ISS Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUhQg.png)

If anyone can help me solve this I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance!